# Does Moonlight support UDP sockets?

Tags: silverlight, udp, moonlight

Seems that Silverlight 4.0 supports UDP.

Any version of Moonlight that supports UDP?

Answer (score 0):

As of today, no, there are no versions of Moonlight (yet) that support UDP. It is a feature that will be implemented before Moonlight 4.0 is released, however.

You may wish to keep track of our progress by either installing the latest [Moonlight 4.0 preview release](http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/download.aspx) or the [nightly builds](http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/nightlies.aspx).